# How to fetch values from nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongodb database for storing data and using mongoose for making schema.Below is my schema:

**expense.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ExpenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  payerid:{
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  paid:{
    type: Number,
    require: true
  },
  owers:[
      {
     owerid:{
       type:String
     },
     amt:{
       type: Number
     }  
    }
  ],
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  amount:{
      type: Number,
      require: true
  }
});

const expense = mongoose.model('expense',ExpenseSchema);
module.exports = expense;
```

Here is my database structure:

[image]

I want to fetch the `owerid` and `amt` values from the array.How can I  fetch this I am not getting idea.Someone let me know.

Comment: Do you want to fetch some specific item of the array based on `owerid`, or you want to fetch the whole array?

Comment: I want to fetch all the `owerid` and `amt` from array

Comment: if you use paths like  `ower.oweid` and `ower.amt` you will get 2 array with all the those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const Expenses= require('../models/expense');

const getExpense = async (expenseId) => {
  try {
    const expense = await Expenses.findById(expenseId);  
    // Now, you can access owers array of the document
    console.log(expense.owers);
    return expense.owers;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: That owers array I am able to get but how can I get `amt` and `owerid` out of that owers array

Comment: Well, the `owers` is an array of objects. So you can only access some particular object and its `amt` and `owerid`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah thats what I want